# How to get ETA when fetch data from postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql

Users can choose the data they want to collect from the database in specific views in my Django project. However, when a large query takes a while to fetch—up to 10 minutes—users are unaware of any errors.

How can I find out about how long it will take to collect data from Postgres? And how do I show that?

Comment: There is no reliable way to get that information.

Comment: Thanks for answer :). I don't know all aspects about postgres and real world aplications with that.  How usually such as this task is done in production? Any recomendations? @Laurenz Albe

Comment: No recommendations, because it just cannot be done.

Comment: 1. Make sure the main page is fully rendered, before loading the data. No user wants to wait 10 minutes to open a page.
2. Show a warning to the user about potential long load time and a spinner while loading
3. Use AJAX to update the page / redirect to the next page once the data is fully loaded